# Does the subset $ B = \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} , r > 0, r^{2} > \frac{1}{2} \} $ of $ Q $ have a small element? A greatest lower bound?

Tags: analysis

I should suppose that it has a small element and find a contradiction, but I did not know how to construct a number that smaller than $ r $ and its square is greater than $ \frac{1}{2} $.

As I am stuck also in the second of determining the greatest lower bound if it exists.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: From what set are you allowed to choose greatest lower bounds?  All real numbers, or only rational?

Comment: Only rational numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $r^2>\frac12$, $r=\frac ab$, $a,b\in\Bbb N$. As suitable number just slightly smaller than $r$, we can try $s=\frac{na-1}{nb}$ with $n$ large enough. But will $s^2$ be $>\frac12$?
$$ s^2=\frac{n^2a^2-2na+1}{n^2b^2}=r^2-\frac{2a}{nb^2}+\frac1{nb^2}>r^2-\frac{2a}{nb^2},$$
hence it suffices to pick $n$ so large that $\frac{2a}{nb^2}<r^2-\frac12$, i.e., 
$$ n>\frac{2a}{b^2(r^2-\frac12)}$$

Comment: What about the greatest lower bound? thank you.

Comment: How can I show that the greatest lower bound does not exist? Thanks.